# Rules for the usage of "me" VS. "myself"?

Tags: nouns

What are general guidelines for the use of "me" and "myself"?

> Did I describe *me* or did I describe Maria?

OR

> Did I describe *myself* or did I describe Maria?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two parts separated by *or* are complete, independent sentences.  As such, the presence of the second half ("did I describe Maria") has no impact on the first half at all.

Thus, the question is, which of these two is correct:

> 1. Did I describe me?
> 2. Did I describe myself?

The answer is (2), because *myself* is the object of the sentence, and *I* is the subject.  Outside of stylized usage, if the (grammatical) subject and object are the same entity, the reflexive must be used for the object.

> - John hit him.  (*John* and *him* are different people)
> - John hit himself. (*John* and *himself* are the same person)
> - John hit John. (must be two different people named *John*)

So, to sum up:

> - I hit him. (grammatical)
> - *I hit himself. (ungrammatical, because subj. and obj. aren't same entity)
> - *I hit me. (ungrammatical, because *I* and *me* are the same entity)

Comment: 'Outside of stylized usage, if the (grammatical) subject and object are the same entity, the reflexive must be used for the object.' No. [Kŏnig and Gast_ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Volker-Gast/publication/281856447_Reflexive_pronouns_and_other_uses_of_'self'-forms_in_English/links/57192f7d08ae30c3f9f2bfeb/Reflexive-pronouns-and-other-uses-of-self-forms-in-English.pdf)  attempt to rationalise the actual situation:

<< **1.1 Optional reflexives** In [English] reflexive pronouns are optional in cases like the following:

(9) a. John saw a snake near him/himself....

Comment: b. Mary pushed the brandy away from her/herself.
c. Liz wrapped the rug around her/herself. // ... // **1.3 Unexpected personal pronouns**
Among the peculiarities of English also the following structures have to be listed:
(11) a. John did not have any money on him (/*himself). b. He likes having children around him. c. Mary has a whole week of travelling before her. d. Mary put all her problems behind her. In sentences such as these reflexive anaphors are excluded. >>